# How to resolve classpath incompatibilities between plugin code and IntelliJ SDK

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, classloader

I am currently trying to develop a plugin for IntelliJ that will use a "core" library. The core library already has it's own dependencies (JAR files) and is used in other non-IntelliJ projects. Unfortunately some of the dependencies of the IntelliJ SDK are the same as that for the plugin core, but with conflicting versions. So far this has been manageable because we remove the dependencies in the SDK and provide the core's dependencies instead, and running the plugin through IntelliJ to work fine. However, I really want to be able to write automated unit tests for the plugin, and this causes problems.

Following the instructions from [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Testing+IntelliJ+IDEA+Plugins), I set my first unit test to extend `LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase`. However, this fails to get past the setUp method, throwing NoClassDefFoundErrors. See the gist of the error [here](https://gist.github.com/Grundlefleck/54a33ca1efe971ded6ff) (picocontainer is the conflicting dependency).

By inspecting the classes loaded while running the plugin, I can see that the same class from a conflicting dependency is loaded in two different classloaders, a `URLClassLoader` for the `com.intellij` dependency, a `PluginClassLoader` for my plugin's dependency. This explains why the plugin can be executed successfully, but the test fails.

A small, self contained example of a project that fails in this way is available here: https://github.com/holger-s/libraryconflict

My question is, what is the recommended way to resolve these conflicts that allows unit testing with the IntelliJ test fixtures?

---

Full disclosure: I have [also sought an answer](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/456490) on the IntelliJ Plugin Development forum.

Answer (score 1):

So this is late, but was running into the same problem, and I fixed it by adding the library under Project Structure/Libraries, then going to Modules/Dependencies, and changing the scope to Provided.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Setting-up+environment+for+PhpStorm+plugin+development